# Joining data points with straight lines (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a pretty simple MatLab code her that perfectly well plots 6 datapoints. The x coordinates from the `dt` list; the y coordinates from the `TempTable` table in row 7. It all works fine, I just need **to join the points with a straight line**.

```
% Plotting T_new(7) vs. dt
dt=[0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.25]    % The time steps
y=[300,320,330,340,345,350]

for i=1:1:6     % Looping through all temperature profiles
    hold all;       
    plot( dt(i), y(i), 'b*-', 'LineWidth', 1);
    title(['Temperatures at nodal point 7']);
    xlabel( 'dt [s]' );
    ylabel( 'T [\circC]' );
    set( gca, 'LineWidth', 1 );
    axis( [ dt(2)-0.1, dt(6)+0.1, 300, 350 ] );
    pause( 0.1 );     % Animation step time
end
```

Shouldn't the dash `-` in `b*-` add these joining lines, or what? What is missing here, since they don't?

Comment: Please add the `TempTable` too.

Comment: @harre I have now changed the table reference into a vector of six values which is added in the code. Same problem, so the table seems not to be the issue. All data used should be in the code now.

Comment: The lines are added only *in the same plot command*. Individual plot commands can't be connected, and they shouldn't. How should matlab know which points to connect, and in what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is your problem. With only one point plotted per iteration, it is impossible for Matlab to know what points to connect. So if you want to use a loop, you'll have to connect the points manually with another `plot`-statement.

A solution without a loop could be:

```
hold all;       
plot( dt, TempTable(7,:), 'b*-', 'LineWidth', 1);
title(['Temperatures at nodal point 7']);
xlabel( 'dt [s]' );
ylabel( 'T [\circC]' );
set( gca, 'LineWidth', 1 );
axis( [ dt(2)-0.1, dt(6)+0.1, 300, 350 ] );
pause( 0.1 );     % Animation step time
```

Comment: @Steeven And if you want a gradual plot with lines, use `plot(dt(1:i),y(1:i),...)` in your original code.

Comment: Further explanation added.